# How to remove leading spaces in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

How to remove leading spaces in plsql

Hi folks,
currently this below gives leading spaces after using 'RTRIM', is there any way i can improvise on this and remove those also if the value is ending with 0 i don't need the 'RTRIM' to remove that 0 since it is part of the solution

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(0.252345, '9990.99999999999999999999'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(0.252345, '9990.99999999999999999999'), 0));
END;
```

Output

```
0.25234500000000000000
      0.252345
```

PS : I used RTRIM to prefix 0 before decimal point.

Comment: Is the blank line after `to_char(0.2` intentional?

Comment: no. i couldn't format properly in stack overflow

Comment: In the editor panel, see the `?` symbol at the top right.

Comment: "PS : I used RTRIM to prefix 0 before decimal point.": Please re-read about [RTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php)

Comment: And, for removing leading spaces, you can use [LTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/ltrim.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FM` in your format to suppress leading space.

```
TO_CHAR(0.252345, 'FM9990D99999999999999999999')
```

Or better still, don't do this in SQL (or PL/SQL for that matter) at all, but handle display issues in your app or Website instead.

The decimal separator is `D` in the format string, not `.` by the way.

Comment: With your suggestion i am able to remove the spaces but is there any way to achieve prefix of 0 before decimal point and if the string is ending with 0 it should not remove that 0.

Comment: You get the zero before the decimal point, because you are using `0` isntead of `9` in the format. And what do you mean with ending? 12.30 is the same as 12.3 and the same as 12.300000. How many zeros do you want?